# Intellij Idea Spring Facet only recognizes resources with application.*

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

Question states it a lot. Is there a way to let any resource file named other than `application.*` to be scanned by spring facet?

Version of IntelliJ Idea is: 2017.1.3

Tagging Spring Boot in the question too, may be someone from that community knows configuration as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2017.2 allows this: Open Spring Facet, select Spring Boot autodetected fileset and click on "Customize Spring Boot" icon in toolbar and enter custom "spring.config.name" value in dialog.